# Odoo How to create line graph with time series data?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I would like to display time series data with Odoo graph view. The graph should look something like this (some example graph i found on the internet):

[image]

Graph X-axis should be date field sorted ASC
Graph Y-axis should be selectable field (price or qty_in_stock)

I need to display values of all products (**multiple lines in the same graph**)

Model fields (new record for selected products created daily)

```
date = fields.Date(default=lambda self: fields.Date.today(), required=True)
product_template_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="product.template", required=True)
price = fields.Float(digits="Product Price", required=True, group_operator=False )
qty_in_stock = fields.Integer(required=True, group_operator=False)
```

I have created tree view and graph view for this model. Views are opened with default group_by on product and records are sorted date ASC. Also default filter is used to display only records created in the last X days (X set dynamically in `fields_view_get()`). I used group_operator=False on price and qty fields to disable sum in tree view, but unfortunately i found out that then I got no data from fields with group_operator=False in graph view so I removed it.

Graph view xml

```
<record id="vendor_connector_tracked_data_graph_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.tracked.data.graph.view</field>
        <field name="model">vendor.connector.tracked.data</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <graph string="Tracked Data Records" type="line">
                <field name="date" interval="day" type="row/>
                <field name="qty_in_stock" type="measure"/>
                <field name="price" type="measure"/>
            </graph>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Graph view result (without group_operator=False). I tried setting col and row and nothing helped.
[image]

Graph view result (with group_operator=False)
[image]

Graph X axis is always wrong (whether with or without data due to group_operator=False parameter).

I am more than happy to provide aditional information about my problem.